# Reformatting text file to be table in csv format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I used PyPDF2 to retrieve tabular data and I put it into a text file. It comes out with each word or number as a new line. I want to specify that the "states" be rows, the "years" to be column headers, and the following numbers to be put into the rows 10 at a time.

The PDF of the file has a good illustration of what I am trying to do. Does anyone have some good ideas as to how to reformat the text file to do so?

Provided here is the link to the pdf which I am taking data from.

```
 file:///V:/Final%20Project/Data/DuckStampSales.pdf
```

My text file looks as such.

[textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLMGv.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have added the python tag to your question since it is not version-specific. Like this you will reach more people. Some additional notes: The pdf you link to is a local URL, for everyone not on your computer the link is dead. Please consider finding and online version of that pdf or reproduce the text some. As for the text file, can you please copy that into your post using a code environment (each line indented by four spaces)?

Comment: Here is the link to the pdf online:

Comment: Duck Stamp Sale Numbers
    State
    Oregon
    Pennsylvania
    Puerto Rico

    Rhode Island

    South Carolina

    South Dakota

    Tennessee

    Texas

    Utah

    Vermont

    Virgin Islands

    Virginia

    Washington

    West Virginia

    Wisconsin

    Wyoming
    Total Annual Sales
    2002-03
    2003-04
    2004-05
    2005-06
    2006-07
    2007-08
    2008-09
    2009-10
    2010-11
    2011-12
    27,789
    26,759